# CSRF token missing or incorrect. Django + jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, django

I trying to implement jQuery File Upload on Django project. But every time I submit an image, an error has occurred: "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."

**models.py**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**main.js**

```
$(function () {
  /* 1. OPEN THE FILE EXPLORER WINDOW */
  $(".js-upload-photos").click(function () {
    $("#image-upload").click();
  });

  /* 2. INITIALIZE THE FILE UPLOAD COMPONENT */
  $("#image-upload").fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {  /* 3. PROCESS THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER */
      if (data.result.is_valid) {
        $("#gallery tbody").prepend(
          "<tr><td><a href='" + data.result.url + "'>" + data.result.name + "</a></td></tr>"
        )
      }
    }
  });

});
```

**template.html**

```
{# 1. BUTTON TO TRIGGER THE ACTION #}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload photos
</button>

{# 2. FILE INPUT TO BE USED BY THE PLUG-IN #}
<input id="image-upload" type="file" name="file" multiple
       style="display: none;"
       data-url="{% url 'add_location_step_3_url' %}"
       data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"'>

{# 3. DISPLAY THE UPLOADED PHOTOS #}
{% for photo in photos %}
<a href="{{ photo.file.url }}">{{ photo.file.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this

```
{# 1. BUTTON TO TRIGGER THE ACTION #}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos" formmethod="post">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload photos
</button>
```

---

if it doesn't work also try to leave it inside a form

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{# 1. BUTTON TO TRIGGER THE ACTION #}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload photos
</button>

{# 2. FILE INPUT TO BE USED BY THE PLUG-IN #}
<input id="image-upload" type="file" name="file" multiple
       style="display: none;"
       data-url="{% url 'add_location_step_3_url' %}"
       data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"'>
</form>
```